# PHPExcel Save file performance

Tags: php, excel, performance, save, phpexcel

I'm generating an excel file containing about 60000 rows in my php script. It takes about 18 seconds to generate the required data and write to objPHPExcel object but when saving it to a local file or sending back to the server it takes more than 30 seconds. Following are save scripts for both scenarios.

save to local file

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("downloads/". $filename);
```

Save output to browser directly

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

is this delay when saving large files expected or are there ways to improve performance on saving?

note: script generating about 3500 excel rows run in about 3 seconds.

Comment: This sounds more like a file system performane issue. Try writing to a temp/in-memory file to compare performance.

Do you have formatting in your XLS file? If no, might be useful to consider wirting CSV file instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do want to have formatting in my file. however for the time being i ended up using a lightwight library called [PHP_XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter) which brought down whole process to around 5 seconds. Of course I lost many features offered by PHPExcel but was sufficient enough to complete the task at hand. I'll try what you've suggested with PHPExcel.

Comment: Sure, if that works for you :) I would also suggest stracing the php process: http://endlessgeek.com/2014/03/strace-php-process-via-apache/